# iMX8M Mini aarch64 to aarch64 Exception switching Issue

Tags: arm64

I can able to switch exception `aarch64(EL3)` to `aarch32(EL1)` but unable to switch exception `aarch64(EL3)` to `aarch64(EL1)` in `ARM Cortex a53`. what goes wrong in this scenario.

There is any particular reason for these kind of issue.

This is my code for aarch64 to aarch64 Exception switching:

```
mov     x2, #(1 << 0)           /* EL0 and EL1 are in Non-Secure state */
orr     x2, x2, #(1 << 4)       /* RES1 */
orr     x2, x2, #(1 << 5)       /* RES1 */
bic     x2, x2, #(1 << 7)       /* SMC instructions are enabled at EL1 and above */
orr     x2, x2, #(1 << 8)       /* HVC instructions are enabled at EL1 and above */
orr     x2, x2, #(1 << 10)      /* The next lower level is AArch64 */
msr     scr_el3, x2

mov     x2, #5                  /* Next level is 0b0101->EL1h */
orr     x2, x2, #(1 << 6)       /* Mask FIQ */
orr     x2, x2, #(1 << 7)       /* Mask IRQ */
orr     x2, x2, #(1 << 8)       /* Mask SError */
orr     x2, x2, #(1 << 9)       /* Mask Debug Exception */
msr     spsr_el3, x2
adr     x2, el1_entry_aarch64
msr     elr_el3, x2
eret
```

Comment: Define "unable".

Comment: aarch64(EL3) to aarch32(EL1) : cpsr           0x1d2 [ #1 nRW F I A ]                                  
aarch64(EL3) to aarch64(EL1) : cpsr           0xaaaaaaaa [ #1 #3 #5 I D #11 #13 #15 #17 #19 SS UAO TCO #27 C N ]    This is what exactly happening spsr_el3 register is not storing into cpsr register in aarch64 to aarch64 conversion. when i switching el3 to el1 cpsr register contain random value like 0xaaaaaa.

Comment: You're returning to EL2, not EL1.

Comment: i tried both levels even though is not working.